# Twitter Bootstrap 3 increasing navbar-header div width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, width, navbar

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header" >
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
      
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/Activity">Activity</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#/Customers">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/Inventory">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/Orders">Orders</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Basically, I've been searching through Twitter Bootstrap 3 and Stack-Overflow for the past 2-3 hours.

I would like to increase the width of the div class `navbar-header` so that I can have a search input that spans the top middle of the nav bar.

Seems like when the navbar collapses it extends the search Too far.

#### [Example in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/educatedrisk/2GxRf/)

Basically I want the same thing as Gmail with the Google Logo, Big Search box, icons/links on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline` on the `form-group`..

Here's a working demo: http://www.bootply.com/Vi3dsd5qLk

Comment: I copied the code as is and get a different result -- the `input-group` is not spanning the width of the navbar.

Comment: Depends on the Bootstrap version